# DynamoDB S3 Imports

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-emr, emr

When [importing from S3 to DynamoDB](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/01/aws-howto-using-amazon-elastic-mapreduce-with-dynamodb.html), does this count towards provisioned write throughput?

I have a service that is only read from, except for batch updates from a multi-gigabyte file in S3. We don't want to pay for provisioned writes all month, and scaling from 0 writes to several million could take a while given the AWS policy of only allowing provisioned rates to double at one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. EMR integration relies on the same API as any client application. As such is is subject to the same throughput policy.

Minor precision:

- minimum throughput = 1 (not 0)
- maximum throughput = 10,000 (not > 1,000,000)

By the way, huge 'scaling' can easily be automated provided that you only double at once. It only takes a couple of minutes to run. Maybe you could also consider storing "incremental" diff instead of the full "multi-gigabyte file in S3". It would save a lot...

The [official optimization guide](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/EMR_Hive_Optimizing.html) for DynamoDB can provide you some useful hints on how to optimize your import.

Comment: Is the a rate limit on how many times in a day you can increase throughput?

Comment: Nope. But can have only one single table in "UPDATING" state at a given time

Comment: Another suggestion from an AWS architect was to create a new table with the desired high write throughput, import, change the application from the old to the new table, and then decrease write provisioning.